# eliminate space between comma and thousands digits in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to fix some data. It is almost 6 million words but I've found that some of it has been separated by commas then a space in numbers. For instance:

```
1, 000, 000 cases were produced of this, however, that is not important.
```

I was using:

```
changed = re.sub(r', \d{3}', r'\d{3}',original.strip())
```

but that changes it to:

```
1,\d{3},\d{3} cases were produced of this, however, that is not important.
```

so it recognizes what needs to be changed, but not what it needs to be changed to

Comment: I think you’re gonna need capturing groups.

Comment: Do you want to remove the comma itself, or just the space?  Your regex suggests you want to remove the comma too, since you didn't include the comma in the replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the digits in a group and then reference the group in the replacement.

```
>>> re.sub(r', (\d{3})', r'\1',original.strip())
'1000000 cases were produced of this, however, that is not important.'
```